# Best container for string search in Qt5

Tags: c++, string, qt, search, containers

In my project I need to determine occurrence of the string in the list of strings. The duplicates in the list are not allowed, and the order is irrelevant.

Please help me choose the best Qt container for the string search.

Comment: If there can't be duplicates then I would say QSet is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a list of strings, Qt provides the **QStringList** class.

Once all strings are added, you can call the removeDuplicates function to satisfy your requirement of no duplicates.

To search for a string, call the **filter** function, which returns a list of strings containing the string, or regular expression passed to the function.

Here's an example, adapted from the Qt documentation: -

```
// create the list and add strings
QStringList list;
list << "Bill Murray" << "John Doe" << "Bill Clinton";

// Oops...added the same name
list << "John Doe";

// remove any duplicates
list.removeDuplicates();

// search for any strings containing "Bill"
QStringList result;
result = list.filter("Bill");
```

result is a QStringList containing "Bill Murray" and "Bill Clinton"

If you just want to know if a string is in the list, use the **contains** function

```
bool bFound = list.contains("Bill Murray");
```

Found will return true.

Comment: Do you have a lot of strings? I suggest trying QStringList first and then if it's too slow, then see if another container is quicker. There's very little code in using it, so you should easily be able to change it at a later date, should you need to.

Comment: I have around 5-20k strings

Comment: If a QStringList is taking too long, split it into several QStringLists objects and process them on separate threads with QThread. Just ensure the number of threads is no more than the number of CPU cores on the machine it's running.